# Handling a SOAP request in NodeJS with PHP documentation

Tags: php, node.js, soap

I'm struggling to convert a PHP code handling a SOAP request into NodeJS.
I tried a lot of things, including npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-soap

I really don't understand how to fit the lines I have in PHP into a NodeJS code. Here it is:

```
$stream_context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    ],
     'http' => [
         'header' => 'MailToken: ' . $token
     ]
]);

$client = new SoapClient(null, [
    'stream_context' => $stream_context,
    'location' => self::MAIL_URL,
    'uri' => 'SOAPService/Mail'
]);

return $client->__soapCall('send', [
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
    'recipients' => $recipients
], null);
```

Could anybody give me a piece of advice?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't help your directly, but when you pass `null` as the first parameter the constructor for `SoapClient`, that means you aren't in WSDL mode anymore. WSDL and SOAP go hand-in-hand, and if you aren't using it, you're pretty much just doing a simple HTTP POST with an XML document. That said, if you are using just a tiny bit of SOAP, I'd recommend looking into just figuring out what the XML payload looks like and switch to simple HTTP. Also, if your code is simple, maybe see if your service has a REST endpoint, too?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I can't get any info on the SOAP server: I didn't code it and nobody is able to get the code (no comment...). All I have is a rest URL but the person in charge of it told me I had to encapsulate my request in SOAP. I don't have any WSDL, only this piece of PHP code which is working. That's why my only hope is to find a brilliant mind on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't use Node.js

Comment: *"Could anybody give me a piece of advice?"* Read some documentation about SOAP to understand how it works. Once it's done, it should be rather easy to switch to another SOAP client.

Comment: That's what I've done before asking the question. Believe me, I have handled a lot of complex projects, all I'm asking here is kind advice and I don't find "RTFM" very constructive. SOAP is clearly not the thing I master, so if an advanced user could help me, it would be great. I know that if I take months to master SOAP I will find the answer by myself, but I don't want to spend time on something I won't use in the future. I need a shortcut from somebody knowing the path.

Comment: If we had access to documentation and an endpoint for testing we could help more. (I know you are between a rock and hard place, too). I'm going to reiterate what I said in the beginning. Run your PHP version, take a dump of the [body](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) and the [headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php), and just make a simple HTTP POST call. Without a WSDL, this isn't worth fighting. The more you learn about SOAP, the more you'll love when it just works and scream when you have to debug the smallest thing.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The parameters are already given in the PHP code he posted. What do you need more?

Comment: @Olivier, I'm telling the OP to abandon SOAP and make an HTTP POST because no one (both here, including myself, and whoever is giving them this task) is helping him with actual code, documentation, instruction, etc. The OP sound like they don't know SOAP that well, and if all they are doing is making an HTTP POST with an XML document, I'd say just keep it simple. It sounds like this is a legacy endpoint so it isn't worth the effort in making/learning anything new/complex.

Comment: I think as is previously mentioned that a plain http post should work. The stream context looks like it is doing two things to me. Setting the headers and it looks like it is not checking / rejecting server certificates (something that you may do if using self signed certs) when using https. Try sending a http post request and making sure that you do not reject unauthorized certs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explanation of how SOAP works in general: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

So, what we learn from there:

1. you can use for instance XMLHttpRequest in node.js using this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest to create the request itself
2. now we can use XMLHttpRequest object to make a call https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
3. here is basic usage of the XMLHttpRequest [creating a post request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send). Derived from that, here is how your request should look like:

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", soap_server, true);

   //Send the proper header information along with the request
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("MailToken", mail_token);

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
   if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
   // Request finished. Do processing here.
   }
   }
   xhr.send(soap_envelope);
4. soap_server = that would be self::MAIL_URL + SOAPService/Mail
5. mail_token = that would be the mail token
6. soap_envelope = this should be a properly constructed XML corresponding the SOAP requirements (read the first url). You can just dump a string there in or you can use library like this: [how to build XML with JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) to generate proper XML SOAP request.

Comment: *"soap_server = that would be self::MAIL_URL + SOAPService/Mail"* Nope, the `uri` option from the PHP code is an XML namespace (as stated [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php): *"uri is the target namespace of the SOAP service"*). On the w3schools page you posted, the uri would be `https://www.w3schools.com/prices`.

Comment: Not really, uri is just a general term. I would assume you can still use a general namespace as in the first url. From the original description server and uri look as typical components to a http request, in which you need a server address and subsequent resource path.